# Writing into table in Word doc using python docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I'm trying to write into tables in a word template my company uses for statement of works,
I already have working code that takes our template file and saves it as a new filename in a different location. The filepath+filename is new_SOWdst_file_name.

This keeps crashing usually for a failure error about this being not writeable.

Pretty new to python. Any advice appreciated.

```
# doc = Document(new_SOWdst_file_name)
# f = open(new_SOWdst_file_name, 'r')
# doc = Document(f)


# if customType == ca :
#     sys.exit()
    

# elif customType == sc :
#     SOWNum = doc.tables[0].cell(4,2).text
#     SOWAuthor = doc.tables[0].cell(6,2).text
#     SOWDescriptor = doc.tables[0].cell(8,2).text
#     SOWPartNum = doc.tables[0].cell(9,2).text
#     SOWDate = doc.tables[0].cell(13,1).text
    
#     SOWNum = 'SOW-'+ PartNum
#     SOWAuthor = 'Cody Nelson'
#     SOWDescriptor = Description
#     SOWPartNum = PartNum
#     SOWDate = now.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
    # doc.save(f)
    # f.close()
    # doc.close()
#     sys.exit()
    
# elif customType == cc :
#     sys.exit()
```

Comment: In line number 2, you are opening file in read mode `'r'`. If you want to write to the file, you should open it in write mode `'w'` i.e. change `f = open(new_SOWdst_file_name, 'r')` to `f = open(new_SOWdst_file_name, 'w')`

Comment: @Lambda I tried the above and anytime I try to open and save the docx like this the resulting document is saved into the location with the proper name but it opens as read only and is completely blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doc = Document(new_SOWdst_file_name)


doc.tables[0].cell(13,1).text = now.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
doc.tables[0].cell(9,2).text = PartNum
doc.tables[0].cell(8,2).text = Description
doc.tables[0].cell(6,2).text = 'Cody Nelson'
doc.tables[0].cell(4,2).text = 'SOW-'+ PartNum

doc.save(new_SOWdst_file_name)
```

Not sure why this works and the other doesn't.
But, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Don't open the file before reading or writing it. `python-docx` takes care of all those details for you. All you need is:

```
document = Document(new_SOWdst_file_name)
# ... do your work with `document`
document.save("new-file-name.docx")
```

Comment: When I try this method nothing is saved into the document. None of the 'work' is done.